# .NET Updating Data in SQL View

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oledb, ssms

I've been asked by my boss to replicate an MS Access feature that we're going to lose shortly after migrating our product to .NET.

The feature is the ability to view and update any data in the database,  particularly Tables or Views, in a tabular grid.

I can do it for pure tables that have a identity column because the SqlDataAdapter can auto-generate the relevant CRUD methods on the fly, to fill / update via DataTables.

However, views are somewhat more tricky. SQL Server Management Studio does allow it. If you click 'Edit top xx rows' on a View, it allows you to edit the data in some columns in what looks to be a standard .NET DataGridView - though it feels a bit magical.

So, a few questions:

How does SSMS infer which primary key to use, even if the key is not in the view?

How does SSMS determine which column inside a view can or can not be edited / inserted / deleted etc.?

What would be my best option to replicate this inside a .NET application?

Is it possible to connect a DataGridView to an old style oledb / obdc connection that has a constant direct connection to the database?

Any guidance as normal will be highly appreciated.

Marlon

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server views can be updated just as if they were a single table, as long as they conform to certain conditions.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> Updatable Views
>
> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as
>   long as the following conditions are true:
>
> Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,
>   must reference columns from only one base table.
>
> The columns being modified in the view must directly reference the
>   underlying data in the table columns. The columns cannot be derived in
>   any other way, such as through the following:
>
> An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV,
>   STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.
>
> A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that
>   uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators
>   UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a
>   computation and are also not updatable.
>
> The columns being modified are not affected by GROUP BY, HAVING, or
>   DISTINCT clauses.
>
> TOP is not used anywhere in the select_statement of the view together
>   with the WITH CHECK OPTION clause.
>
> The previous restrictions apply to any subqueries in the FROM clause
>   of the view, just as they apply to the view itself. Generally, the
>   Database Engine must be able to unambiguously trace modifications from
>   the view definition to one base table. For more information, see
>   Modify Data Through a View.

I don't believe SSMS is doing anything special - editing the contents of a view offers exactly the same functionality as editing the contents of a table. If the user attempts to make a change that does not conform to the above conditions, SSMS will likely display an error.

> How does SSMS infer which primary key to use, even if the key is not in the view?

It doesn't. SQL Server does since only one underlying table can be edited at a time.

> How does SSMS determine which column inside a view can or can not be edited / inserted / deleted etc.?

Again, it's SQL Server that determines this, not SSMS.

> What would be my best option to replicate this inside a .NET application?

As long as all your views conform to the above conditions, simply do the same as you're doing for tables, but be ready to handle the errors from users doing something they can't (this implies some user training will be required, just as it would be if they were using SSMS directly).

Comment: In addition, in case the view is NOT updatable, you can STIL Lmake it so by providing an instead of update trigger ;) Which then can do the real table inserts.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's ok if I can indeed get SQL to do all the work for me (which is preferable) but with normal .NET I don't have a constant connection to SQL so I need some form of a WHERE clause to pass along with the update statement to update the correct row in the view. Would selecting data along with the ROW_NUMBER function work, or I could try using a DataGridView in virtual mode with a ADODB RecordSet which can do direct edits to the database.

Comment: You should use whatever single column, or combination of columns, identifies the rows in the view. If there is no combination of columns able to do this job (i.e. it's feasible that the view may contain rows with identical values in every column) then you'll need to add a new column to the view which can be used as an identity. As long as all the underlying tables have primary keys, the view will also have a primary key composed of the combination of all the underlying primary key columns, though all those columns must be exposed by the view, and things change if the view has some aggregation.